# preg_match fail after upgrade Wamp

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, wamp

To prevent malicious users from trying to exploit keys we make sure that keys are only named with alpha-numeric text and a few other items, using `preg_match`.

This is the code:

```
if (!preg_match('#^[&a-zA-Z0-9\.:_/-\s]+$#uD', $str)) {
    exit('String not valid:' . $str);
}
```

This function working well until the last week, when the customer update `WAMP` on test server. Using string as `dverse.session`, the code enter in `EXIT()`. I've checked the regular expression with http://www.phpliveregex.com/ but the regular expression is working well. What could be the problem?

Comment: The servers have the same php versions ? The regex syntax can change depending on the php version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have minus sign escaped in the regex:

```
if (!preg_match('#^[&a-zA-Z0-9\.:_/\-\s]+$#uD', $str)) {
    exit('String not valid:' . $str);
}
```

Comment: or put it in the beginning or the end.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Thanks to everyone, the solution was:

```
if (!preg_match('#^[&a-zA-Z0-9\.:_/\-\s]+$#uD', $str)) {
        exit('String not valid:' . $str);
    }
```

This was caused by changing PHP version. You can check it at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ using the code:

```
$str = "dverse.session";

if (!preg_match('#^[&a-zA-Z0-9\.:_/-\s]+$#uD', $str)) {
    exit('String not valid:' . $str);
} else {
    echo "OK";
}
```

Changing the PHP version from 5.5.5 to 5.6.2 (or 5.5.18) appear the error. Thanks!